# Querying a database relationship with carbon in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I'm trying to select the picture with the most likes from a category the previous day. However, my query returns a null result. My pictures are related to the likes through a has many polymorphic relationship.

Here is my query:

```
$foodOfTheDay = Picture::withCount('likes')
        ->where('picture_type', 'food')
        ->whereHas('likes', function($query) {
            $query->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::yesterday());
        })
        ->orderBy('likes_count', 'desc')
        ->with('user')
        ->first();
```

Here is my likeable relationship:

```
public function likes()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Like', 'likeable');
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you try `where('created_at', '<', Carbon::today()->setTime(0, 0))`

Comment: Thank you, but this still returns null

Comment: what i might suggest is to install debugbar or clockwork to print queries - they will show you the problematic part in the queries. you may try one by one to identify problem

Comment: I'm wondering if the whereHas clause might be causing the problem

Comment: They add an exists sub query to main query. It might be. The tools i suggested are useful to show raw queries. You may execute them on database directly to see which part is problematic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$foodOfTheDay = Picture::withCount('likes')
        ->where('picture_type', 'food')
        ->whereHas('likes', function($query) {
            $query->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon\Carbon::yesterday()->startOfDay(), Carbon\Carbon::yesterday()->endOfDay()]);
        })
        ->withCount('likes') // count yesterday's likes
        ->orderBy('likes_count', 'desc')
        ->with('user')
        ->first();
```

or this:

```
$foodOfTheDay = Picture::withCount('likes')
        ->where('picture_type', 'food')
        ->whereHas('likes', function($query) {
            $query->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::yeserday()->startOfDay())
                  ->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::yesterday()->endOfDay());
        })
        ->withCount('likes') // count yesterday's likes
        ->orderBy('likes_count', 'desc')
        ->with('user')
        ->first();
```

Both of them should return picture with the highest likes the previous day (yesterday)

This query selects the picture with most likes without taking into consideration the other days' likes:

```
$foodOfTheDay = Picture::where('picture_type', 'food')->withCount(['likes' => function($query) {
        $query->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::yesterday()- 
>startOfDay(), Carbon::yesterday()->endOfDay()]);
    }])
    ->orderBy('likes_count', 'asc')
    ->with('user')
    ->first();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this selects the picture with the most likes overall, as opposed to the picture with the most likes yesterday. For example, if a picture had 10 likes yesterday, those likes should not be taken into consideration when selecting the picture of the day the following day.

Comment: Didn't you say you want to select picture with the most likes yesterday?

Comment: I found the answer by passing the whereHas function as a parameter of a withCount function. Your answer selected pictures with likes entered the previous day and then went on to select the total likes for that picture. I edited your answer.